# Is there any problem with converting this excel formula to javascript?

Tags: javascript, excel

Here is the excel formula:

```
=E2-(J2*2*G2)-(K2*E2*2)/30+IF((L2+M2)>60,((L2+M2)-60)*H2+60*G2,(L2+M2)*G2)+(N2/$AE$1)*$AE$2+(Q2*$AE$5+P2*$AE$4+O2*$AE$3)
```

Here what I tried (Javascript):

```
                    var E2 = $("#sentence").val();
                    var J2 = $("#deduction").val();
                    var G2 = 55145;
                    var K2 = $("#absence").val();
                    var L2 = $("#overtime").val();
                    var M2 = 0;
                    var H2 = 50050;
                    var N2 = $("#transportation").val();
                    var sixty;

                if ((L2 + M2) > 60) {
                    sixty = ((L2 + M2) - 60) * H2 + 60 * G2;
                } else {
                    sixty = (L2 + M2) * G2;
                };

                var result = E2 - (J2 * 2 * G2) - (K2 * E2 * 2) / 30 + sixty;
```

I couldn't find the way to conver this part of formula:

```
+(N2/$AE$1)*$AE$2+(Q2*$AE$5+P2*$AE$4+O2*$AE$3)
```

---

**Here I found the problem:**

Even if one of the variables sets to null, then the formula does not work properly.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like some pretty basic math.

```
let total = (N2 / AE1) * AE2 + (Q2 * AE5 + P2 * AE4 + O2 * AE3 )
```

This is basically impossible to translate without seeing the actual spreadsheet but that should get you started. Also, make sure to take into consideration order of operations because the computer is going to evaluate it from left to right unless there are parenthesis (where it will evaluate those first).

Comment: What is AE1 ? AE5 ? Why we have a letter after the other letter here ? Blocks have one letter and one number right ?

Comment: @M.imp the contents of the cells you showed in your formula stated in your question. If you had provided the data…